# Find disjoint sets in a table with nested table colum sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, nested, set, multiset

these are the sample data :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CourseList AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(64);

CREATE TABLE department (
courses  CourseList)
NESTED TABLE courses STORE AS courses_tab;

INSERT INTO department (courses)VALUES (CourseList('1','2','3'));
INSERT INTO department (courses)VALUES (CourseList('4','5','7'));
INSERT INTO department (courses)VALUES (CourseList('1','2'));

commit;

 select d1.courses
from department d1
where not exists (select 1 from department d2 
  where d1.courses<> d2.courses and d1.courses submultiset of d2.courses);

commit;

Result:

CourseList(1,2,3)
CourseList(4,5,7)
```

The query returns the correct data, CourseList that are not subset of any other CourseList of the table.

Some idea on how to do it without the subquery, I think that it can be done using join with the same table but i don´t know how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer your subquery, myself. But an alternative is:

```
select d.courses
from department d
MINUS
select d2.courses
from department d2, department d1
where d1.courses<> d2.courses
and d1.courses submultiset of d2.courses;
```

Comment: just curious, when would it be practical to use `submultiset`?

Comment: um... when you need to know if one set is a submultiset of another?

Answer (score 1):

A "not exists" query can be expressed as a join using the anti-join pattern.

```
select d1.courses
from department d1
left join department d2
   on d1.courses <> d2.courses
  and d1.courses submultiset of d2.courses
where d2.sources is null
```

The idea is to *try* to outer self join using the same condition as inside your *not exists* clause, and then in the where clause only keep the rows where no such join existed.

I usually use the primary key in the where clause.  It's required that the column not permit nulls (so that you can tell that there wasn't a match).

Using an anti-join is sometimes faster, and it can make it clearer what indexes might help, but it can also be confusing to read if unfamiliar with the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but this might be what you're looking for:

```
select d1.courses
from department d1
cross join department d2
where d1.courses<> d2.courses 
and d1.courses not submultiset of d2.courses;
```